# ClaimRow function for dynamic coupon

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I've been having a look at the ClaimRow function to build a dynamic coupon code email and wondered if anyone can help me with a few things...

It's advised to add an IsClaimed field to your DE for validation - my question is, is this relating to when the code is actually claimed by the end-user, or when it is allocated to the email send? Is the ClaimRow function only used when the code is claimed online?

Here's my current scenario (offline redemption): 
Manual .csv import of customers with CouponCode, CouponDiscountAmount, and ExpiryDate relating to an Email Address & BookingRef. Once imported into SFMC it's rather easy, but generating this data is extremely manual as some of the variable fields aren't stored e.g. discount amount. Customers will then need to call to redeem. Is this the best way of doing things?

Comment: To my understanding: When the claimrow function will be executed the isClaimed column will be changed. That would be the case meanwhile the sending process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there is an API/FTP integration in place, Marketing Cloud has no way of knowing whether or not a code has been redeemed. This is an issue a lot of SFMC users are facing, as it is very much dependent on the e-commerce application and it's ability to report on redeemed vouchers. If at all possible, for many clients only a manual process of uploading CSV files into data extensions remains the only option.

You should, when generating the voucher codes, include information on the campaign related to the code, the value (e.g. 10% discount, free shipping, etc), in order for you to report it within SFMC.

ClaimRow, as you correctly assume, only indicates via isClaimed column whether or not a voucher code has been assigned to a sent email and hence cannot be assigned to a different recipient.

Comment: Thanks Lukas, really appreciate your help :)

Comment: You’re welcome @CB2020 - remember to mark the answer as accepted